# Can one circuit only compute one boolean function?

Tags: digital-logic

Can one circuit (with fixed position of gates and wires) only compute one boolean function?

Comment: Related: combinational vs sequential logic.

Answer (score 3):

No. There are lots of examples of circuit that can be reconfigured to compute different boolean functions at different times.

**ALU**: (arithmatic logic unit) has some inputs that determine an *op-code* which selects different operations to perform on the other inputs.

**Multiplexer**: Can be used to implement arbitrary logic functions on some inputs, depending on the inputs to other inputs.

**SRAM**: (static random access memory) can be programmed to implement arbitrary logic functions on the inputs applied to its address pins.

**EEPROM**: (electrically-erasable programmable read-only memory) can be used to implement arbitrary logic functions like an SRAM, but doesn't lose its program when not powered.

**FPGA**: (field programmable gate array) The king of programmable logic, can be programmed to implement very complex logic on very large numbers of inputs, as well as implement state machines. Internally, an FPGA is typically implemented using a large number of SRAMs.

**CPLD**: (complex programmable logic device) nowadays usually just a small FPGA, earlier generations had a more rigid logic structure, but with more predictable behavior than FPGAs.

**PAL**, **GAL**: (programmable array logic and gate array logic) Earlier generations of programmable logic, nowadays largely superseded by CPLDs.

Comment: Neither ALUs nor multiplexers have multiple Boolean outputs for a single input. In these cases you are ignoring the control inputs.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast, with different opcode inputs, a typical ALU could compute AND, OR, NOT, etc., on it's operand inputs.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast, my understanding of OP's question is s/he wants a circuit that can calculate AND right now, and later can be reprogrammed or reconfigured to calculate OR.  If s/he  wants to get AND and OR outputs at the same time it's trivially done by putting an AND gate next to an OR gate and hooking them up to the same inputs.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can loop the logic back on itself an create a circuit with internal state. Then the output is not a boolean function of the input. one simple example of this is a flip-flop.  a more complex example is a computer.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTV6Cb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

It would fairly trivial to construct a single *circuit* (not a single gate, but that's not what you said) that performs multiple logic functions.  For example, just take a 2-input AND gate, 2-input OR gate, and a 2-input XOR gate, and parallel each of their 2 inputs (**X** and **Y**).  Then run the three outputs to a 3:1 multiplexer.  You would need two control lines (**A** and **B**) to select the function, with the output appearing at **Z**.

Note that all three logic functions (AND, OR, XOR) are always being performed in parallel; the control lines just select which one of the three output lines to pick from.

```
   A  B
   0  0    do nothing (0 output)
   0  1    AND
   1  0    OR
   1  1    XOR

 A=0, B=1 (AND)        A=1, B=0 (OR)         A=1, B=1 (XOR)
   X  Y  Z               X  Y  Z               X  Y  Z
   0  0  0               0  0  0               0  0  0
   0  1  0               0  1  1               0  1  1
   1  0  0               1  0  1               1  0  1
   1  1  1               1  1  1               1  1  0
```

[image]

This is sort of the way a 1-bit slice of an ALU (arithmetic logic unit) works, except the control lines for it don't necessarily correspond directly to the basic logic functions -- see [my answer here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/193921/1322) for more info and a schematic.

Comment: I see above a circuit that computes a boolean function of 4 inputs, two unlabeled inouts and one each labeled A and B